# Need help redirecting with a bearer token

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, redirect, http-headers

I'm trying to redirect from one webpage to another, but the other webpage is on a separate domain. Our two companies have a business relationship and I'd like to use their auth bearer token in the redirected http request for authentication with my backend service.

How do I do that? AFAIK, you can't set the header in  elements, nor can you set them with window.open or window.location. I would need a way to effectively redirect from the affiliate website to my own, while passing the bearer token because I plan to use that token for authentication within the backend services that my website will call. I don't think I can use a cookie because cookies aren't cross domain.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You can pass the token in the redirect url itself and some flag also , but on the application you have to write the logic to fetch the token from URL if flag is there then you can set the token in header and send request.

Comment: Are you reinventing the OAuth2 authorization_code flow? If so, look into that because it solves this problem and more.